# Embed nested collections form in Symfony 6

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, nested, embed

I want to embed nested collections on three levels, for the second level it works but not the last one i can't get the prototype on the last level.

I work with Symfony 6 and i use stimulus.

```
class FormType1 extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field1')
            ->add('formType2',  CollectionType::class, [
                  'entry_type' => FormType2::class,
                  'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => FormData1::class,
        ]);
    }
}

class FormType2 extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field2')
            ->add('formType3',  CollectionType::class, [
                  'entry_type' => FormType3::class,
                  'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => FormData2::class,
        ]);
    }
}

class FormType3 extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field3')
            ->add('field4');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => FormData3::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is the prototype:

```
<div {{ stimulus_controller('form-collection') }}
    data-form-collection-index-value="{{ form.formType3|length > 0 ? form.formType3|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}"
    data-form-collection-prototype-value="{{ form_widget(form.formType3.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"                 <<============
>
    <ul {{ stimulus_target('form-collection', 'collectionContainer') }}></ul>
    <button type="button" {{ stimulus_action('form-collection', 'addCollectionElement') }}>Add a tag</button>
</div>
```

In Stimulus Controller `form-collection` i get the prototype in this way

`item.innerHTML = this.prototypeValue.replace(/__name__/g, this.indexValue);`

The `prototypeValue` It return an `empty string`